# How can I toggle lists by clicking on their containing block?

Tags: html, jquery

Good day. I have the following HTML. How to open/close li by clicking on blocks?

```
<div class="recent-box">
    <div class="recent-box__head">
        <span class="recent-box__head-task">#04</span>
        - Serial number filtering.
    </div>
    <ul class="recent-box__list">
        <li class="recent-box__list-item">
            <span class="recent-box__list-date">18:24 -</span>
            <a href="#" class="recent-box__list-link">User</a>
            sent a response
        </li>
        <li class="recent-box__list-item">
            <span class="recent-box__list-date">18:24 -</span>
            <a href="#" class="recent-box__list-link">User</a>
            sent a response
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please provide more information in your question that what exactly you have done and what should be the result ?
I see below result after execute the code : 

`#04 - Serial number filtering.  
18:24 - User sent a response  
18:24 - User sent a response`

Comment: Chand Jogani, I have a block 'recent-box' ... I want on click recent-box div and show/hide data inside ul block ... like accordion ... It could be many same blocks.. only data inside different.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to make an effort and show what you've tried. We're not a free coding service. Be sure to mention that you can't change the markup (and any other important details).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("recent-box");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.recent-box {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.recent-box:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="recent-box">
  <div class="recent-box__head">
    <span class="recent-box__head-task">#04</span> - Serial number filtering.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel">
  <div class="recent-box__head">
    <ul class="recent-box__list">
      <li class="recent-box__list-item">
        <span class="recent-box__list-date">18:24 -</span>
        <a href="#" class="recent-box__list-link">User</a> sent a response
      </li>
      <li class="recent-box__list-item">
        <span class="recent-box__list-date">18:24 -</span>
        <a href="#" class="recent-box__list-link">User</a> sent a response
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Chand Jogani, thanks a lot. but I can not change markup.